# Does it matter which side up a seed is planted?

Tags: planting, germination

I've got some seeds which I couldn't identify and I'd like to know if it makes any difference if I plant them the "wrong" side up or sideways. Would it significantly decrease its chances to grow? Or does it depend on the seed? My seeds vary in sizes from 2mm to 6cm in average diameter, but I'm interested in answers for all possible sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really,  no, it doesn't matter - what's more important is planting them at the right depth, which varies between varieties of seeds.